# binary tree search for string c++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to implement string search method in binary tree. It takes node* as an input, and outputs node* again.

The problem is it does not work properly due to some pointer exceptions, it gives me the error.

If I am not clear at some point please let me know.

Thank you in advance

> -var-create: unable to create variable object error

```
zoo_tree::node* tree_tools::search(zoo_tree::node* from,string animal) {
if (from != NULL) {
    if (from->question == animal) {
        return from;
    }
    if (from->question != animal) {
        search(from->left, animal);
        search(from->right, animal);

    }
}
return NULL;
```

}

However, the code above works, what is the difference?

zoo_tree::node* tree_tools::search(zoo_tree::node* from,string animal) {

```
if (from == NULL)
    return NULL;

if (from->question == animal)
    return from;

if (from->question != animal)
{
    search(from->left, animal);
    search(from->right, animal);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious error in your code: the recursive calls to `search()` don't return the instance when it is not null, because recursive calls must recursively return.  This means that unless the root is the searched node, a NULL will be returned.